# mount windos partitions with same parameters as Files ( file browser ) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, mount, headless

I want to run for, some data analisys, my computer in headless mode. It is a dual boot windows /ubuntu 16.04 system.

I regularly just click on the file browser, on the offered local partitions to automatically mount local partitions I am interested in each moment. No questions ask, it just works.

This is the fstab line

/dev/mapper/isw_cjbadfefde_ASUS_OS5 on /media/julian/New_Volume type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

However, I am finding imposible to manually replicate such mount when running headless ( no access to file browser )

Can somebody give me a hint on how to make the very same mount, manually ?

Thanks.

JC

Answer (score 0):

If I get your request right you want to access the oder partition via the terminal right?
I have no system with the same requirement at the moment, but maybe i can help anyways.
So you probably have to mount the disk manually.
With:

```
fdisk -l
```

you can get an idea of what you can mount and expecially what type (ntfs, cifs...). 
Then with:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/what_you_want_to_mount  /folder_where_you_want_to_mount_to/
```

This is also described pretty good at this page: [Mount windows partition onto ubuntu linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: your link points nowhere. It states clearly what I want to mount and where in my question.

Comment: link is fixed. The command is also written in my post ;)